# Httpd start on access on port 80, how to stop it?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, httpd

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 with httpd, and each time I am accessing to the port 80 the service starts ! I would like to stop it without uninstalling apache, so far I tried :

```
service httpd stop
chkconfig httpd off
```

Comment: Did you configure httpd to listen on port 80 ? if you did, remove it

Comment: Right, I commented out the line with "listen 80" in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and now it is perfect, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `httpd.conf` & comment out the line where it says `listen 80`